# способ обработки данных в Laravel (DI)

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

решил попробовать использовать DI в своем проекте, написал следующий код:

web.php:

```
...
Route::post('/delModelX/{modelx}', [ModelXController::class, 'delModelX']);
...
```

ModelXController.php:

```
...
public function delModelX(ModelX $modelX){
    dd($modelX);
}
...
```

в dd получаю объект выбранный по id, логично, но у меня эта `$modelX` логикой привязана к пользователю по полю user_id, получается что мне перед обработкой необходимо выполнить проверку `$modelX->user_id == Auth::id()` что лишает всякого смысла DI т.к. я там же могу вызвать метод сервиса в котором проверю оба условия (id, user_id).

как более правильно сделать в такой ситуации? вообще нужен ли здесь DI?

Comment: ваша проверка "==" - это бизнес логика. А DI не занимается и не должен заниматься бизнес логикой.

Comment: Для этого есть политика и гейты что бы проверять может ли текущий пользователь что то сделать